multiple clients chat server select problem
I tried to use non-blocking functions on the client side (select and mcsvrt) and debugged it, but when the debugger gets to the select() line then it stops and I don't know what's wrong with my code.
This is the server:
import socket
import select

SERVER_IP = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 33333
SERVER_MSG_LENGTH = 6

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
server_socket.listen(5)

open_client_socket = []
msg_to_send = []


def send_waiting_msg(wlist, sender_socket):
    for message in msg_to_send:
        (client_socket, data) = message
        length = str(len(data)).zfill(6)
        for client_socket in wlist:
            if client_socket != sender_socket:
                msg = length + data
                client_socket.send(msg.encode())
        msg_to_send.remove(message)


def main():
    flag = True
    print("server is running and listening...")
    while flag:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([server_socket] + open_client_socket, open_client_socket, [])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is server_socket:
                client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
                open_client_socket.append(client_socket)
                print("connection with {} has been made".format(address))
            else:
                length = current_socket.recv(SERVER_MSG_LENGTH).decode()
                try:
                    data = current_socket.recv(int(length)).decode()
                    if data == "quit":
                        open_client_socket.remove(current_socket)
                        print("connection has been closed")
                    else:
                        print(data)
                        msg_to_send.append((current_socket, data))
                        send_waiting_msg(wlist, current_socket)
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)
                    exit(-1)
            if len(open_client_socket) == 0:
                flag = False
    server_socket.close()


This is the client:
import socket
import msvcrt
import select

SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 33333
SERVER_MSG_LENGTH = 6

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

open_client_socket = []


def main():
    flag = True
    while flag:
        ready_to_read, _, _ = select.select([client_sock, msvcrt.getch()], [], [])
        for source in ready_to_read:
            if source == client_sock:
                try:
                    length = client_sock.recv(SERVER_MSG_LENGTH)
                    print("send")
                    data = client_sock.recv(int(length)).decode()
                    print(data)
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)
                    exit(-1)

            elif source == msvcrt.getch():
                send = msvcrt.getch()
                if send == b'quit':
                    flag = False
                length = str(len(send)).zfill(SERVER_MSG_LENGTH)
                msg = length + send.decode()
                client_sock.send(msg.encode())
    client_sock.close()


I tried making a for loop like on the server side for the list that I put in the select(), and it is supposed to make the chat non-blocking.

There is nothing wrong with your code blocking at select(). It is a blocking operation.

When i debugged it the code stopped at the ready_to_read line on the client code like an infinite loop

It didnt even gave me an error and the server kept running

Yes. That’s correct. It’s  a blocking operation. It blocks until a client connects or a socket is ready to read. You don’t seem to understand your own code, and specifically you don’t seem to understand select(). Look it up. But there is very little point in using non-blocking mode in clients.

But when i checked non blocking methods i saw that select can be used instead of recv. Can i use select as a non blocking somehow?

I repeat. You don’t seem to understand what it does. You need to look it up. You can’t get a tutorial on non-blocking mode here. At least you won’t get it from me.

select() is a blocking function (when you don't specify a timeout). The conditions you are asking it to wait on are not being satisfied, which is why the code stops when select() is called.
On the server side, you are asking select() to unblock when a new client connects to the server, or when the server receives data from an existing client.
On the client side, you are asking select() to unblock when the client receives data from the server.
These are normal socket operations to wait on.
However, the real problem I see with your code is a misuse of msvcrt.getch().  You cannot wait on msvcrt.getch() with select() to way you are attempting to do so.  You are calling msvcrt.getch() first (which is a blocking operation that waits until a keystroke is available), and then you are passing the returned character to select(), which is wrong.
You need to instead have select() wait on sys.stdin itself, and then you can call msvcrt.getch() when stdin is readable.
You can alternatively put a timeout on select() and then call msvcrt.kbhit() to test if you should call msvcrt.getch().
Alternatively, you could implement a msvcrt.getch() loop in a separate worker thread.
Either way, note that msvcrt.getch() returns a single character, but you are expecting it to return a whole string, which will never happen. You need to change how you read user input.  See How to Read from stdin in Python, for instance.
